# Casting generic MyClass<Child> to MyClass<Parent> in C#

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Suppose I have a parent class `Animal`, with subclasses `Cat` and `Dog`. I also have a `Building<T>` where T can be of any `Animal`.

```
public class<T> Building
{
    public T Inhabitant {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I want to create some buildings with cats and some with dogs (based on parameters available only at runtime). For this, I am trying to create following method:

```
private Building<Animal> populateBuilding(string animalKind)
{
    if(animalKind == "cat")
    {
        return new Building<Cat>;
    }
    if(animalKind == "dog")
    {
        return new Building<Dog>;
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, I cannot do this because compiler tells that `Building<Dog>/Building<Cat>` cannot be cast to `Building<Animal>`. I found several examples where similar issue is described but with using of lists (e.g. `List<Animal>, List<Dog>, List<Cat>`). However, I do not use lists in my case, and wonder if it is still same situation.

Comment: Reason is `covariance and contravariance`. More specifically, Image if you can do something like this `Building<Animal> b = new Building<Cat>` then you can`b.Inhabitant = new Animal()` . As you see you assign `Animal()` object to `Cat` reference type property , that is not permitted.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking for an explanation for why this is happening? Or are you asking for a suggestion on how to design your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read some article on covariance and contravariance, for instance, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

In your case the class `Building` is so designed that it does not allow for either.

Suppose it were allowed to use `Building` covariantly. Then it would permit the following code snippet:

```
var dogHouse = new Building<Dog>();
var house = (Building<Animal>) dogHouse; // Casting to base class

house.Inhabitant = new Cat(); // Inhabitant of a Building<Animal> is any Animal
dogHouse.Inhabitant.Bark(); // Meow!
```

A generic may be used covariantly with its type parameter `T` if its methods only return values of type `T` (as return values or `out`-parameters). A generic may be used covariantly with its type parameter `T` if its methods only accept values of type `T` as parameters. In your case, there are both, namely, `get_Inhabitant` returns an `Animal` and `set_Inhabitant` accepts an `Animal`.

Moreover, in C#, as it has been rightly pointed out in comments, the concepts of covariance and contravariance are only applied to interfaces and delegates.

Comment: Though I do not understand fully covariance and contravariance (read that article a bit earlier today), but your example described the problem quite good. Thanks!

Comment: covariance and contravariance are only valid for interfaces, not classes.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, yes, indeed. And also delegates (which are essentially syntax sugar for interfaces with a single method).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as follows:

```
private Building<Animal> populateBuilding(string animalKind)
{
    var building = new Building<Animal>();

    if (animalKind == "cat")
    {
        return new Building<Animal>
        {
            Inhabitant = new Cat()
        };
    }
    if (animalKind == "dog")
    {
        return new Building<Animal>
        {
            Inhabitant = new Dog()
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```